# How to convert bash array to PSQL array

Tags: arrays, bash, psql

I have a bash script and an array variable in it.
The array is initialized as...

> ARRVAR=( 0001 0002 0003 )

Now, I want to use the array to query in PSQL.
This is my query...

> QUERY1="SELECT * FROM table WHERE column1 && '$psql_array'"

*column1* is type varchar[] and it is compared to another array (psql_array), which should be the bash array variable converted to PSQL array.

Is there any possible or simple way to convert bash array to PSQL array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
# printf to a variable (psql_array) replacing single quotes by two single quotes
printf -v psql_array "'%s'," "${ARRVAR[@]//\'/\'\'}"
# remove the trailing ,
psql_array=${psql_array%,}

# check
echo "($psql_array)"


# or to have a postgresql varchar[]
# escape double quote between double quotes
printf -v psql_array "\"%s\"," "${ARRVAR[@]//\"/\\\"}"
psql_array=${psql_array%,}
echo "{$psql_array}"

# or easier
printf -v psql_array "'%s'::varchar," "${ARRVAR[@]//\'/\'\'}"
echo "ARRAY[${psql_array%,}]"
```

Comment: I removed the single quotes in '%s' and replace the parethesis in echo "($psql_array)" to be curly braces. 
Thank you for the idea.

Comment: ok i've edited the answer to have a  postgresql array, you have to be careful  to the sql injections, that's why the quotes should be handled

Comment: Understood. Thank you!